# display text with image that can be zoomed

Tags: iphone

I hope to display text with image as blow on a row of UITableView.

[image]

[image]

when I tap "+" , the image will be zoomed.

I know there is a way to use UIWebView/html5 to realize this.
Is there a solution rather than using UIWebView?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0):

add your text to image view by addsubview and then apply UIPinchGesture to image view so image view will be zoomed with text.